# What is the fastest way to find out the download percentage based on the image?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to get % of [progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R5sb.png) in game.

To do this, I recognize the color of the line and determine how many pixels on the left are painted in this color. And this method is very slow. Because the progress bar is 230 pixels long, and I have to do a lot of looping queries.

```
Loop, 230
{
    PixelGetColor, color, firstPixel, Y
    
    if (color != 0xFFBE39) {
        break
    }
    firstPixel := firstPixel + 1
}

percentage := Ceil(firstPixel / 2.3)
```

And the difficulty is that progress can change at any moment. But not only to the right, but also to the left.

Please tell me the fastest way, how I can know the get % based on this picture

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an iteration based algorithm. You can improve the speed multiple folds.

You simple devide everytime by 2 the maximum length of the bar, to get roughly the loading bar position.

You will somewhat lose in precision (but you can always refine with your first approach to go back to 100% precision).

This code is not complete but could get you started.

```
MaxBarPixel := 256
MiddlePixel:=MaxBarPixel/2
Iterations:=20
Loop,
{
Iterations:=Iterations+1
If (Iterations>20) { Break } 

PixelGetColor, color, MiddlePixel, Y
    
if (color = 0xFFBE39) {
MiddlePixel:=MaxBarPixel-(MaxBarPixel-MiddlePixel)/2
} else {
MiddlePixel:=(MaxBarPixel-MiddlePixel)/2
}
    
}
```